# How to create column and lines charts from this simple spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create two charts from a local cycling club's account spreadsheet. These will provide "at-a-glance" overviews of the state of the current finances.

The spreadsheet has a columns with incoming monies (receipts) and the date received, with similar columns for outgoing money (payments).

[image]

The first chart will sum up the incoming outgoing columns and display these in a simple column chart. A quick glance should show that the incoming column is taller than the outgoing (hopefully!). This is where I hit my first problem - I don't seem to be able to use SUM in the chart:

[image]

I have ended up having to reference a cell containing the sum of the column, but this sum takes into account a cell (C3) which contains balance brought forward from a previous year which I want to ignore for this chart:

[image]

The other chart I want is a line chart showing amount of money on the y-axis and time on the x-axis. The receipts line should go up over the year (again, hopefully) and the payments should go down. I'm not even close to getting this correct:

[image]

It should be something like this, so as the year passes (x-axis) the amount (y-axis) of receipts and payments increases:

[image]

How can I create these charts?

Spreadsheet is here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-8DzB6c3rZ8evfNJ8iRcO_2BletbH81FV4hIis0-Fj4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you share us how you created the chart using your data? or enable the edit access on sheet so that we can easily copy it.

Comment: Edit permissions applied - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-8DzB6c3rZ8evfNJ8iRcO_2BletbH81FV4hIis0-Fj4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Apologies but I'm still confused on how your 2nd chart should look like. Do you want the Receipts to have cumulative sums and the Payment graph to be the same as your example above but with different date?

Comment: Have added a sketch showing what I'd like from the line chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your graph and found some issues:

1. On the first graph, you cannot use formula in `Data Range`. The input should only be a **A1 notation**. Creating another entry on `B16:C17` and use it as graph data is correct.
2. If you want to ignore `C3`, just change the formula in your `C16` with `=SUM(C4:C8)`
3. Based on the sketch you've provided for the second graph, The data will only go up by getting running total or cumulative sum of each data per category (Receipts, Payments). Unfortunately, Google Sheet does not have built it function that can automatically do that. You have to create another column for cumulative sum.

**Example:**

For Receipts, insert this in **D4**:

```
=ArrayFormula(If(len(C4:C8),(SUMIF(ROW(C4:C8),"<="&ROW(C4:C8),C4:C8)),))
```

It will create another column with cumulative sum of `C4:C8`.

[image]

For Payments, insert this in `H3`:

```
 =ArrayFormula(If(len(G3:G7),(SUMIF(ROW(G3:G7),"<="&ROW(G3:G7),G3:G7)),))
```

[image]

5. The dates from **Receipts** and **Payments** are different, if you only use the dates of Receipt, the data for Payments will be inaccurate. You need to create another table that will combine the dates and data of those two categories.

Try this:

J2: `={A4:A8;E3:E8}`
K2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J2:J11, A4:D8, 4, false)))`
L2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J2:J11, E3:H7, 4, false)))`
Make sure to add Labels on K1 and L1.

It should look like this:

[image]

Once you have the data, just highlight `J1:L11` and Go to **Insert -> Chart -> Convert it to Smooth line chart -> Check Aggregate**

The graph should look like this:

[image]

### References:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: Perfect - thank you